# What is my voice type?

Tags: voice, vocal-range

my name is Joudrick Sanchez, my grandmother is a very nice singer, not famous but, she is great singer, she teach me certain things, but she doesn't told me anything about my voice type, either my teacher. I sing with tenors or bass very rarely.

My vocal register:

Low notes:
E2 - C3

Chest notes:
C3 - D4

Belted notes/Mixed:
C4 - G4 - A4 
(I hit A4 very rarely, only when I happy or inspired) (normally it's just a F#4 or a G4)

Head voice & Falsetto:
C4 - C5 - E6 (sometimes I can hit a C5 in head) (not all times)

Many people told me that my voice is very weird...
:( what am I ? Baritone, tenor, low tenor, high baritone???

Comment: I'd say "Just sing, don't worry about labels." I've been a professional singer [studio session pop/rock] for 35 years & I still neither know nor care what a classically-trained professional would classify me as.

Answer (score 1):

If your teachers don't consider it helpful to nail down a particular voice type at your current stage of training, do you think some random collection of people never having heard you will fare better?

You need basic stamina across your accessible range anyway regardless of what you are going to end up singing since you can get hoarse on any untrained part of your vocal apparatus.  It's quite likely that when you train your voice and connect and blend the different registers and work on achieving consistent quality, that the worthwhile range that people will be interested in hearing will be considerably smaller than your theoretically accessible range.

But it will likely require quite a bit of development before you can sensibly make such choices with some confidence.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you're a bass. 
The bass range is generally something like E2-E4. E2 is only rarely used, so the low notes you're describing are similar to those of a bass.

In terms of upper range, the highest I've had to sing, as a bass, is F4.

So, you're probably a bass with a good falsetto and quite a large bass. Whether you're a bass or a baritone depends on how confident you are with those low and high notes, and how 'deep' your voice sounds.

If you want to know for sure you can sing repertoire for a range of voice types, and from what you feel most comfortable singing you can deduce your voice type.